# IOS: Registering new app on Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, registration

There must be an easy answer to this one....

I am trying to integrate my latest IOS App to Facebook.  I have not used Facebook before, so just set up a "company" page with basic information on my firm.

I'm following all the Facebook links i.e. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/

But I cannot get beyond Step 1 (LOL).  Whenever I click the link "Step 1: Registering your iOS App with Facebook," it keeps taking me to my company's Facebook Admin screen!? I cannot find a way to register my App off this screen.  Where is the "Add new app" link??

I'm going in circles.  Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to register an App under a Business account, and you have to create (or lend) a personal account. And keep in mind: Facebook frowns upon incorrect information, so should be a legit person or your account will be suspended when (not if) they find out.

Secondly you have to authorize your Facebook account. For example: by entering mobile phone no. and entering code from a text FB will send you (more info: http://www.facebook.com/confirmphone.php) or entering CC information (more info: https://secure.facebook.com/cards.php)

When you (finally) have an authenticated account:

https://developers.facebook.com/apps Is the location you should be looking at.

Over at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/ `Step 1` describes the creation of a Facebook App. (rather simple, by clicking on "Create New App")

Hope this helps! Good luck!

Comment: Thanks xCoder.  I realized that too after hours of searching.  You'd think this would be made more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you are attempting to create a Facebook App with your "page user".  IE you clicked "Use Facebook as..." and clicked on one of your pages.

You can not create an application in this way.  Applications **must** be created by "real" users.  You're going to want to follow that tutorial you posted to and use **your** user.

If you are hesitant to use your own account, ask your boss to use his or request from your clients login credentials to open the application on their account.

---

The reason behind this is so that Facebook can track "bad" applications back to **real people**, people who had to verify their account by submitting a mobile phone or credit card number.